# Изменение текста в кнопке Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/LBEpzg

После нажатия "вид:таблица" нужно чтобы вместо текста "Товар в корзине" была галочка (для примера это просто буква V). Попытался сделать селекторами, посмотрите что не так

```
 $('.btn_buy').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  $(this).html('Товар в корзине').attr('href', '/basket/');
});

 $('.view').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  $('.goods__item').addClass('view-table');
});

 $('.goods__item .view-table .btn_buy').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  $(this).html('V').attr('href', '/basket/');
});
```

Comment: добавь к вопросу html-разметку, чтобы можно было запустить твой код

Comment: на codepen же ссылку прикрепил в начале

Answer (score 1):

У вас тут две проблемы.

1. Вы пытаетесь повесить обработчик на несуществующий элемент
2. Лишний пробел в селекторе.

Вот так работает

```js
$('.btn_buy').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  $(this).html('Товар в корзине').attr('href', '/basket/');
});

 $('.view').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.goods__item').addClass('view-table');
   var table_btn = $('.goods__item.view-table .btn_buy');
   table_btn.each(function(){
    if ($(this).html() == 'Товар в корзине'){
      $(this).html('V')
    }
   });
   table_btn.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).html('V').attr('href', '/basket/');
  });
});
```

Comment: круто. Но я не учёл вот ещё что:
нажимаем на кнопку "в корзину" - теперь получается "товар в корзине". Переходим на "вид: таблица" и остается "товар в корзине", а нужно чтобы была галочка "V". Вот тут без вашей помощи пока никак не могу :(

Comment: @StepanIvanov Добавил проверку.